# Is it possible to pass two or more parameters into a macro? How can I identify them in body of macro?

Tags: macros, latex, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass two or more parameters into a macro? How can I identify them in body of macro?

I want to define my own macro, e.g., `myfoo{width=4, height=5}`.
I know that it can be done by defining custom macro like as `\def\myfoo width=#1,height=#2{ \#1=#1,\#2=#2}`, calling it by `\myfoo width={4},height={6}v`.

But in my situation, there are more than 8 parameters to enter, and I regard that `\myfoo {1},{2},{3},{4},...,{8}` is not smart rather than `\myfoo {1,2,3,...,8}`.

Is it possible to pass several arguments with that format？
And if possible, how to identify individual parameters in its(myfoo's) body?

Comment: There are a lot of packages which you can use for key/value interfaces, see https://www.ctan.org/topic/keyval

Comment: ... and please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting You're post is a bit hard to read